# Node.js environment variable with multiple key/values readable by node.js?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I would like to create a .env file that has a single environment variable that provides multiple key/values readable by node.js.

For instance:

```
USERNAME=firstname:John,lastname:Doe
```

Then something like:

```
require('dotenv').config()

let myEnvVariable = process.env.USERNAME
let firstName = myEnvVariable.firstname
let lastName = myEnvVariable.lastname

console.log(fistName, lastName)
// expected result: John Doe
```

Is something like this possible? If so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be easiest if you just put JSON as the environment variable value.  Then, you can just get the value of the environment variable and do `JSON.parse()` on it and have a fully formed Javascript object as the result.  Then, you don't have to invent your own format and don't have to write your own parsing code.

In your environment:

```
USERNAME={"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"}
```

Then, in your code:

```
const user = JSON.parse(process.env.USERNAME);
console.log(user.firstname);
console.log(user.lastname);
```

FYI, this is exactly the kind of things JSON was invented for - a text-only standard format for expressing data that can be generated or parsed easily from nearly any language.

Comment: This is so much better. You're always a friend @jfriend00!

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of anything like that... but you could work defining your own format for the variable so that you can achieve something like that...

Following your example you could work on a parser that would do it...

```js
const USERNAME="firstname:John,lastname:Doe,phone:countryCode:55,phone:number:99999999999";

const parse = str => {
  const output = {};
  str.split(',').forEach(part => {
    const keys = part.split(':');
    const value = keys.pop();
    let def = output;
    keys.forEach((key, idx) => {
      if (idx === keys.length - 1) return def[key] = value;
      if (!def[key]) def[key] = {};
      def = def[key];
    });
  });
  
  return output;
};

console.log(parse(USERNAME));
```

I've never heard of anything like that... but you could work parsing out the format that you created yourself...

Comment: I was just thinking about this as you answered... Sometimes an obvious answer isn't so obvious when working through a problem... Even when the answer is simple!